# How to use js.erb views in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Is there possibility to use `js.erb` views in Rails 6 application? I get

```
MyController#my_action is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []
```

error for actions using `js.erb` views after migration to rails 6.

In my action I just assign value to instance variable:

```
  def next_question
    @lesson = lesson
  end
```

In routes I have

```
  put ':package_id/lessons/next_question', to: 'lessons#next_question', as: 'next_question'
```

And there is form for submit this request

```
 = form_tag next_question_path(@package), method: :put, remote: true
```

If I create (for test) `html.slim` file, everything works well. 
If I add `format.js` to controller, I get `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Comment: Add more code, show us how you are submitting the form/link, and what does your controller action look like.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh please see updates.

Comment: do you have rails-ujs in your javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a view file `next_question.js.erb`, then do this

```
def next_question
  @lesson = lesson

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Also, enable `ujs` in `application.js` file, add this line

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
```

Give it a try!

Comment: If I add `format.js` to controller, I get `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Comment: I just edited my answer, add `require("@rails/ujs").start()` in `application.js` file

Comment: I ran `yarn add @rails/ujs` and then added `require("@rails/ujs").start()` to application.js. I still have `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error

Comment: `import Rails from '@rails/ujs'; Rails.start();` solved problem. Thank You for all suggestions.

Comment: Sure, no problem, by the way, what is the difference between `import Rails from '@rails/ujs'; Rails.start();` and `require("@rails/ujs").start()`

Comment: Both should behave the same way

Answer (score 1):

In rails controller method you need to define the format of the requests the method can respond to by adding a respond_to block in the method. If there is no respond_to block present then by default the method only respond to html requests. For js or any other request you need to add a respond_to block.

```
def next_question
  @lesson = lesson

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

this will tell the method that it needs to look for a js.erb file named next_question.js.erb, you can also specify the file name like this `format.js { render partial: 'filename' }` and then the method will look for and respond with `filename.js.erb` file.

Comment: Lack of this line is not a direct reason, it previously worked without it.