# Using js.erb file to change the content of an HTML element in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

I'm trying to use AJAX to replace the inner HTML of a div element when I press a button. The div should change to a simple form like this, which will create a "contribution" resource when filled out:

```
<%# ???.html.erb %>

<h2>Make a contribution:</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [ @event, @event.contributions.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I'm still new to Rails, but I've managed to use [this tutorial](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/) to get partway there. So far, I've written something like this:

```
// contribution_script.js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('[data-js-new-contribution]').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        divElement = ... // get the div element
        $('#' + divElement.id).html("<%= j (render partial: '???') %>");
    });
});
```

This does successfully replace the content of the div, but since this is in a .js file rather than a js.erb file, it doesn't process the Ruby code and simply changes the div to the raw string.

Here's what the tutorial says about using .js.erb files:

> Put this code in a file with an extension of .js.erb, with the name of
> the current action (like create.js.erb) & inside the views folder.
>
> On the controller you can render this view just like any other view.

This is confusing to me: I get that my .js.erb file has to go somewhere in my views folder, but what is my "current action?" The page where this div will be displayed comes from views/events/index.html.erb, so I guessed that my current action is "index" in events. Based on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60900787/how-to-use-js-erb-views-in-rails-6), I wrote the following in my events controller:

```
def index
    @events = Event.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```

Then I took the JavaScript code above, renamed it "index.js.erb," and put it in my views/events folder. This doesn't seem to do anything. So, how do I make this work? Thanks for your time!

Bonus question: once I do get the js.erb file working, how can I actually render the form from an html.erb file? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127934/rendering-partial-in-js-erb-file), but I'm still unsure how to set up the partial so it will have the necessary information about the event which the contribution will be added to.

Comment: you can render a hidden form and show it when the button is clicked